# HTTP Get return multiple types

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api, get

I'm writing a web service and I am attempting to add a response to a Get request. The difficulty is, I have multiple types that need to be returned. So initially I have a base class of:

```
public abstract class AbstractSource
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

followed by two derivatives:

```
public class DatabaseSource : AbstractSource
{
}
```

and

```
public class WebSource : AbstractSource
{

}
```

These classes will eventually have more of their own specific elements. In my controller class I have the following test code:

```
public class DataSourcesController : ApiController
{
    AbstractSource[] sources = new AbstractSource[] 
    { 
        new WebSource { name="WebPath"},
        new DatabaseSource{name="DB Source"}
    };

    public IEnumerable<AbstractSource> GetAllDataSources()
    {
        return sources;
    }
}
```

Now when I run this I get a serializationException. Is it even possible to return mulitple types like this?

Comment: Can you share your serialization exception? What serializer are you using? How do you expect the client to make the "find" the right type to bind back to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounded like you are trying to use get the data in XML.

The XML Serializer (e.g. the `DataContractSerializer`) doesn't know how to deserialize `AbstractSource` into either `DatabaseSource` or `WebSource`, and so you will need to snap the `[KnownType(...)]` attributes on your `AbstractSource` class:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[KnownType(typeof(DatabaseSource))]
[KnownType(typeof(WebSource))]
public abstract class AbstractSource
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I thought it was something like this but had gone down the path of using [XmlInclude] rather than [KnownType]. Thanks!